# HardFault when running code from RAM in CortexM0

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, arm, cortex-m

I'm currently developing firmware for an Arm Cortex-M0+ microcontroller and I'm facing a rather interesting issue. I'm not looking for any answers but rather would like to share the problem with other developers so I can (hopefully) shed some light on the issue I'm facing. I will describe it below:

I have a program that dynamically loads (properly compiled and linked) code from an external Flash Chip, to be executed straight out of the MCU RAM. The interesting is that I can perfectly execute the RAM-loaded code when running in step-by-step (via debugger), but it will always crash [formally HardFault] when freely running. I've tried to disable all interrupts, I've double checked the instructions, memory addresses, byte alignments, everything, but I still cannot pinpoint a reason for the exception.

Have some of you any hint of what could be happening? I'm very interested to know more about your experiences! Thanks,

**Update 1 (30/05)**

*Free run* in this case, means not setting a breakpoint right before the branch to RAM. Whenever I step into the branch and execute the instructions in RAM it will run correctly and return. Wherever the breakpoint is not there (and thus the MCU goes zooming thought the branch) the HardFault is observed. Notice that it will crash even when booting up with the debugger engaged but not having the breakpoint set.

**Update 2 (30/05)**

I'm using a **Cypress S6E1C3 Series Arm Cortex M0+ FM0+ Microcontroller**.

**Update 3 (30/05)**

After digging around and playing with the code, I could get it to work properly! It however brought up more questions than answers for me. Reading the official ARM documentation about the BLX instruction ([BLX](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHFJFDG.html)) I found out that the LSBit of the branch address *determines the CPU instruction mode* (1 causes it to run in Thumb mode). By explicitly setting this bit, **I get the code to always work, even in *free-run mode***. The thing is, the code in RAM has not been compiled in Thumb mode, and there is not *apparent* reason why running the code step-by-step with the debugger would cause the instruction mode to change... Any ideas?

K.

Comment: Does your chip support speculative prefetch?  I don't think so, but if it did it might be [ARM prefetch workaround](//stackoverflow.com/q/46118893) there they neglected to make I/O or other regions of physical address space not prefetchable.  (And so speculative loads or code-fetches from them were resulting in hard lockups.)

Comment: It's possible that the debugger runs a startup script that loads various registers in the MCU, to prepare the MCU to run the code. When free running, you need to make sure that the boot code loads all of those registers, in the same order, with the same values.

Comment: I've checked the datasheet and manual and I could not find any reference to speculative pre-fetch, despite being a good starting point... I've noticed that when in free run, the last address held by PC before the HardFault is exactly the first address **in RAM** that the MCU tried to execute.

Comment: I highly doubt this *debug side-loaded boot code* mentioned by user3386109 is the reason for the faults. I say so because **I see the crash even when I bootup with the debugger**. **It only works if I set a breakpoint *right before the branch-and-link instruction* that brings the MCU to run in RAM space**, which I think is quite suspicious...

Comment: Note that I would help if you specified the actual MCU rather than just saying "ARM Cortex-M0+". Many vendors have known quirks which could explain your behaviour.

Comment: Good point Turbo J, I'm currently working with a **Cypress S6E1C3 Series Arm Cortex M0+ FM0+ Microcontroller**.

Comment: Is there any mechanism that would let you find out *where* the HardFault happened?  Is it on the branch instruction itself (or code-fetch for the instruction after)?  Or does it run for a while before crashing?

Comment: Is hardware failure a possibility?  Have you stress-tested the RAM with code running from flash?  Back-to-back instruction fetch might be stressing memory timings in a way that single-stepping isn't?

Comment: Hey Peter Cordes, I'm not sure where the crash happens but if I would have to guess, I would say it happens **after the branch is executed**. I say so because PC (R15) will always point to the address of the first instruction in RAM. and I also see that the link register (LR) has always the correct return address (in Flash). The crash happens always immediately and it is not like it ran for a while and then randomly crashed. I'm not sure whether a hardware failure could be the reason, because I see the same problem when running this code in a second unit.

Comment: Peter Cordes, do you have any reference of pipeline and instruction timing in Arm?

Comment: I have an update...!

Comment: To notify people when you reply, use `@username`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the branch address (as correctly pointed out by @PeterCordes). The branch to RAM was performed by the following code (slightly adjusted for this audience):

```
// Prepare address and Function Pointer
uint32_t codeBufferAddress = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(&buffer) + offset;
void(*methodFromRAM)(void*) = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void*)>(codeBufferAddress | 0x01);

// Branch to RAM
// thisPointer holds an object byte-stream...
(*methodFromRAM)(reinterpret_cast<void*>(thisPointer));
```

Note that in line 3 `codeBufferAddress` is or'ed with `0x01` (`codeBufferAddress | 0x01`), which ensures that the branch will be taken in *Thumb Mode*. By the moment I posted this question, the value held by `codeBufferAddress` was `0x20003E40`, which clearly does not set the LSBit and thus would force the MCU to run in *ARM Mode*.

I think the compiler would not be able to infer and adjust the branch mode, because the address is *dynamically generated*  (even though I think it could be a bit smarter and force all branches to run in *Thumb Mode*, since my MCU can only decode Thumb).

Anyways, when running in step-by-step mode, I could not observe any changes in the target address, and for now I can only guess it forces the MCU to run in *Thumb Mode*... but this is only a guess. Any ideas?

K.

Answer (score 1):

**Cortex-M *only* supports Thumb mode, not ARM mode**, so telling your compiler to compiler for Cortex-M0+ guarantees that it will create Thumb2 code.

That's why you need to set the low bit of your target address.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Instruction_sets
>
> Only Thumb-1 and Thumb-2 instruction sets are supported in Cortex-M architectures; the legacy 32-bit ARM instruction set isn't supported.

If you actually look at the code bytes in memory, you'll see they're Thumb2 instructions.

**The only question is how your debugger managed to make it *not* fault.**  Perhaps it has to handle BLX specially anyway, and doesn't emulate the fault-if-switching-to-ARM-mode on Thumb-only microarchitectures behaviour.  Or maybe just handling the single-step interrupt ends up returning properly in Thumb mode.

---

"legacy" is a bit of an overstatement for ARM mode in general, I think; I thought high-performance ARM chips (with large instruction caches) could still benefit from ARM mode getting more done with fewer instructions and easier access to more registers.  Anyway, that's just Wikipedia's phrasing.